# loading csv into nvd3 to make discrete bar chart

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have the following CSV file:

```
Fun,Stupid,Yes,No
50,-20,100,70
```

I'd like to load it into nvd3 to make a discrete bar chart. I know it's easy but it's taking me way to long to manipulate the data.

I've tried the following:

```
d3.csv("/path/to/file", function(data){
                console.log(data);
                 });
```

and I get the following object which isn't working with nvd3:

```
[{Fun:50, Stupid: -20, Yes: 100, No: 70}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nvd3 is expecting a fairly specific data form so you need to get your data into that form.  The form that it is expecting is:

```
[
    {
        key: "totals",
        values: []
    }
 ];
```

Where the empty array is filled with the objects from d3.csv and note that nv is **expecting** the name of the array of your objects to be called **values**.

So the first step is to create an empty object like this:

```
var exampleData = [
    {
        key: "totals",
        values: []
    }
];
```

Then fill it with your data:

```
data.forEach(function (d){
    d.value = +d.value
    exampleData[0].values.push(d)
})
```

This all needs to be inside your d3.csv call.

To use this format you need to have your csv file organised into columns with your names in one column and your values in another like:

label, value

Fun, 50

Stupid, -20

And here's a link to a [working example](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7243857)